# how to set a disabled button gray or shaded?

Tags: android

I have an xml that contains buttons that has image backgrounds. some of them are disabled but when I put an image background on it, the disabled buttons will not be set in gray background.

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable selector background, having different images for different states,

Comment: can I code it on my java class? something like this. if button is disabled then background color = gray

Answer (score 0):

What you need are `selector` tags.You dont even need to care about programming `onFocus()` etc.Its very easy and simple.You need to construct an xml layout once and it will do the rest.

after adding your drawable button backgrounds to the drawable folder you need to add a
selector like this one:

**(res/drawable/new_button.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Now just set this drawable to your button background like:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
```

Your works done.
[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) is tutorial with sample project source code for you to follow.

Comment: then you should mark this post as answer.This helps other users here on stackoverflow.